# Parsing String To Int C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I am getting a compile error "Input string was not in the correct format" on certain characters in my code

I want to extract the first and second number from a string.

This works:

```
    string input2 = "22+55";
    int firstnum2 = Int32.Parse(input2.Substring(0, input2.LastIndexOf(@"+")));
    int secondnum2 = Int32.Parse(input2.Substring(input2.LastIndexOf(@"+")));
```

The same code breaks in the following scenerio on "secondnum"

```
  string input = "22x55";

    //compiles
    int firstnum = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf(@"x")));

    //exception
    int secondnum = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf(@"x")));
```

The same code breaks in the following scenario on "secondnum"

```
  string input = "22/55";

//compiles
int firstnum = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf(@"/")));

//exception
int secondnum = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf(@"/")));
```

Not sure why "+" works but the other 2 cases do not?

Comment: Why do you prefix "+" and "/" with @?

Comment: Look at the actual strings that you're parsing.

Comment: I also tried 'x' and '/' does not work

Comment: `Int32.Parse(input2.Substring(input2.LastIndexOf(@"+") + 1));`

Comment: This really could have been solved by introducing some intermediate variables to contain the extracted number as a string, then inspecting the value of that in the debugger. Are you familiar with using the debugger in your IDE? Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: To be honest I believe this would be a good opportunity to look at RegEx.

Comment: You may be interested in `string.Split` which takes care of both searching for the separator and making the substrings (excluding the separators).

Comment: "I am getting a compile error" - no, you are getting a runtime exception. This is an important difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have this:

```
string input2 = "22+55";
int firstnum2 = Int32.Parse(input2.Substring(0, input2.LastIndexOf(@"+")));
int secondnum2 = Int32.Parse(input2.Substring(input2.LastIndexOf(@"+")));
```

This line yields `+55`:

```
input2.Substring(input2.LastIndexOf(@"+"))
```

And in the same way that -55 is a valid integer, so is +55 (i.e. negative 55 and positive 55).

You really want this (not the addition of `+ 1` after `LastIndexOf("+")`:

```
string input2 = "22+55";
int firstnum2 = Int32.Parse(input2.Substring(0, input2.LastIndexOf(@"+")));
int secondnum2 = Int32.Parse(input2.Substring(input2.LastIndexOf("+") + 1));
```

`input2.Substring(input2.LastIndexOf("+")+1)` will yield `55`.

Now all of your examples work:

```
string input2 = "22+55";
int firstnum2 = Int32.Parse(input2.Substring(0, input2.LastIndexOf("+")));
int secondnum2 = Int32.Parse(input2.Substring(input2.LastIndexOf("+") + 1));

string input = "22x55";
//compiles
int firstnum = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("x")));
//exception
int secondnum = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf("x") + 1));

string input3 = "22/55";
//compiles
int firstnum3 = Int32.Parse(input3.Substring(0, input3.LastIndexOf("/")));
//exception
int secondnum3 = Int32.Parse(input3.Substring(input3.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FJOPD58334).

Answer (score 2):

You should add `1` in order not to include separator into second value:

```
string input = "22x55";

//compiles
int firstnum = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf(@"x")));

//should parse now
int secondnum = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf(@"x") + 1));
```

If you have *many* possible separators (`+`, `x`, `/`), you can try *matching* numbers with a help of regular expressions:

```
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 int[] numbers = Regex
   .Matches(input, "-?[0-9]+")
   .Cast<Match>()
   .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
   .ToArray();

 int firstnum = numbers[0];
 int secondnum = numbers[1];
```

Comment: In a situation like in the OP RegEx is hard to beat! And with such a simple pattern it makes a great introduction to the power RegEx brings. Nicely done. IMO should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: The beauty of this RegEx is it allows negative numbers even(!) when the operator is  "-" (minus sign). This means an input string = "-15--23" would result in two entries in the array. `firstnum = -15; secondnum = -23;`

Answer (score 0):

`input.LastIndexOf("x")` returns the index of the `x`-char, so the substring includes it.

```
int index = input.IndexOf('x');
string firstNumber = input.Remove(index);
string secondNumber = input.Substring(index + 1);
```

A safer approach is using `string.Split`:

```
string[] tokens = input.Split('x');
int[] numbers = tokens.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

or the supersafe but long version:

```
int[] numbers = input.Split('x')
    .Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out int i) ? i : new int?())
    .Where(nullableInt => nullableInt.HasValue)
    .Select(nullableInt => nullableInt.Value)
    .ToArray();
```